# How do I stop the bootstrap.css file from trumping mine in GWT?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, gwt

I'm using GWTBootstrap in a GWT project.  bootstrap.min.css has the following definition:

```
.table th, td {
    ...
    padding: 8px;
    ...
}
```

I want the padding set to 2px.  however, when I try to override it with my .css file, I find out that bootstrap.min.css is loading last, no matter what I try.  When I load the file in the head of my html file, it still gets loaded a second time, and that second load trumps my file.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `important!` to your rule:

```
.table th, td {
    padding: 2px !important;
}
```